# Scheduling console app from Global.asax ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, win32-process

I have mail service that runnable as standalone console app. How I can schedule launching this service from Global.asax code?

Comment: Have you tried Hangfire?

Comment: This solution is not possible, instead write a console application then host as a windows service. Your webapp will be released after 20 minutes (by default setting on IIS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very good idea. You do not want to start long-running processes in your app pool because if they crash, then w3wp.exe crashes and your site goes down. Instead, consider installing the service as a windows service. You can then check the service is running in your code, and, if not, try and start it. There are other options though. This http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx should give you some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful!